# Drag and drop using a class method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a range of drag drop activities all working fine on my quiz. (From answering questions to selecting an avatar)

There is a lot of repetition of the code and I am thinking it would be better implemented from a class and call the method each time that I use a drag drop.

Firstly can this be done? and secondly would I need a new method for the dragging and dropping?

Any thoughts or rough ideas would be great.

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
pictureBox2.DoDragDrop(pictureBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Set background image of panel to selected avatar'
    panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Is a Web Forms or Windows Win Forms application?

Comment: Could you give some code as example that is getting repeated and that you'll like to refactor ?

Comment: I added the code.

I was thinking a class called drag and a the methods inside for the drag and drop

Comment: My usual way for such a situation is to create a Controller class that handles all the code. The controls register (and maybe unregister) to it, maybe with a few extra params, depending on what you need in the code. The the controller hooks up the necessary events upon registration and you're good. I have done this for several cases including resize- and move controllers, not d&d yet but it should work just as well...

Comment: ...Refactoring existing code is a good situation because you can see every dependce there will be and provide for it in the registration calls. My controllers almost always are static and have List<control> or such for the registered controls..

Comment: Thanks TaW, my question is how to I determine the picturebox each time if I have it in a class?

Comment: Very unclear exactly what code is getting repeated.  Random guess: write *one* event handler for *all* pictureboxes.  That's why it has a *sender* argument.

Comment: Hans nails it: you can cast the event's `sender` to some type and if it isn't null you can use it. Then you can use its properties to further distinguish between, say 16 PictureBoxes.. - Also you could write a subclass that hold tthe d&d knowledge; this is the __inheritance__ way; the controller is the __composition__ way to write oop code..

Comment: Sorry, I wish to use a class to handle all my drag and drop in the game.

So the 'DoDragDrop(pictureBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);'

and the 'BackgroundImage = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to avoid duplicating the same events of several controls you should use common events:

```
private void commonPBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox PB = sender as PictureBox;
    if (PB == null) return; //or throw an exception

    PB.DoDragDrop(PB.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void commonPanel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void commonPanel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Panel Pan = sender as Panel;
    if (Pan == null) return; //or throw an exception

    //Set background image of panel to selected avatar
    Pan.BackgroundImage = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
}
```

Select the respective controls and enter the event names into the respective event name slots in the event pane of the properties tab.

Note how I cast the `sender` param of the event to get a types reference to the control that triggers the event. If the cast goes wrong the reference is set to `null`.

If you want more control and more flexibilty you may consider creating a `DragAndDropcontroller` class..:

```
static class DnDCtl
{
    static List<Control> Targets = new List<Control>();
    static List<Control> Sources = new List<Control>();

    static public void RegisterSource(Control ctl)
    {
        if (!Sources.Contains(ctl) ) 
        {
            Sources.Add(ctl);
            ctl.MouseDown += ctl_MouseDown;
        }
    }

    static public void UnregisterSource(Control ctl)
    {
        if (Sources.Contains(ctl))
        {
            Sources.Remove(ctl);
        }
    }

    static public void RegisterTarget(Control ctl)
    {
        if (!Targets.Contains(ctl))
        {
            Targets.Add(ctl);
            ctl.DragEnter += ctl_DragEnter;
            ctl.DragDrop += ctl_DragDrop;
            ctl.AllowDrop = true;
        }
    }

    static public void UnregisterTarget(Control ctl)
    {
        if (Targets.Contains(ctl))
        {
            Targets.Remove(ctl);
            ctl.DragEnter -= ctl_DragEnter;
            ctl.DragDrop -= ctl_DragDrop;

        }
    }

    static void ctl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox PB = sender as PictureBox;
        if (PB != null) PB.DoDragDrop(PB.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        Panel Pan = sender as Panel;
        if (Pan != null) Pan.DoDragDrop(Pan.BackgroundImage, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    static void ctl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    static void ctl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel Pan = sender as Panel;
        if (Pan != null) Pan.BackgroundImage = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

        PictureBox PB = sender as PictureBox;
        if (PB != null) PB.BackgroundImage = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I have coded symmetric actions for `Panels` and `PictureBoxes` to show how you can handle different controls.
- I have created but not used `Lists` of sources and targets. For more complex projects you will find them useful.
- I have coded both `Register` and `Unregister` methods. You can register after some condition and unregister when it no longer applies
- Such a Controller is good for dynamically alowing or disallowing Drag&Drop for controls, esp. when you create them dynamically.
- You could also pass around delegates to decouple the dragdrop action from the controller.

Also note that some folks sometimes do prefer to use the `MouseMove` event over `MouseDown` esp. as it won't so easily interfere with making a  selection.

`ListView` has a dedicated event instead, `ListView.ItemDrag`, which obviously should be used when registering!

Comment: Yea I think it is the Controller that I was thinking of, I am going to have to practice this. Thank you for your extremely helpful feedback and explanations.

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete noob, how do I accept an answer?

Comment: TaW thank you so much for your help, I have managed to get the common controls working for my drag and drop. I have one more question.

Can I place this code into a Class and use it across a number of different forms?

Comment: Well, the controller code is a class and if you place it anywhere in your project, except __within__ another class you will be able to use it anywhere. All the methods are static and independent from the outside, relying only on the `sender` and the `e.Data` parameters, so yes, it will work across forms. __That is__ If you use the just __corrected__ version of it - I had added the `DragDrop` event hooks to the source instead of the target! My fault, sorry!

Comment: I have implemented the above code, I am having trouble unregistering the sources - I want to do it after the image has been dropped on the target picture box.

Comment: Can you tell me a little about the trouble you have? Note that you need to be sure to register each event only once or else the event gets called more ofteten than once; the register and unreister calls must match!

Comment: I am working on a board game, players select an Avatar at the start, I want to stop them selecting the same avatar. Currently I use the drag drop above, and on the Mousedown event I set the selected avatars visible to false - which works but is flawed.

Comment: If you want to allow only one dragdrop action for a __target__ you unregister in the dragdrop e.g. like this: `UnregisterTarget(Pan);`

Comment: - If instead you want to allow only one dragdrop action for the __source__ you need to create a reference: `static Control source = null;` in the controller class, set it in the mouse down: `source = sender as Control;` and test, unregister and clear it in the dragdrop: `if (source != null)   {   UnregisterSource(source);
   source = null;    }` In this case you should remember which was the previously chosen avator so you can re-register it for re-selecting it later.

Comment: Thanks again, one last question (if you dont mind) I want this avatar to be linked to the player object so it is displayed on all future forms. 

In my player class can I assign an Image property? I was going to assign a value (eg image1 =1, image2 = 2 etc) and use a switch statement on each new form to get the image from resources.

But that seems very repetitive and unnecessary...

Comment: I would avoid creating many clones of a Bitmap. If you have it in the resources you can can store the string you use to access it. But not knowing your classes and program code it is a little hard to advise.