# Invalidating all controls in a winform causes infinite calls of OnPaint method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Extented controls.
First one is called `LiveControl` which is inherited from `PictureBox` which have Resizing,Rotation, Move,... Methods.
Second one is called `DrawPanel` which is inherited from `Panel` which is meant to be the parent for several `LiveControl`s.

I did several things to reduce filckering and also leaving trails when one `LiveControl` moved over another. and finally I achieved it even better than I expected with the following codes in `LiveControl`:

```
MouseUp += (s, e) =>
{
    foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls.OfType<LiveControl>())
        c.Refresh();
};
MouseMove += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Control x = (Control)s;
        x.SuspendLayout();
        x.Location = new Point(x.Left + e.X - cur.X, x.Top + e.Y - cur.Y);
        x.ResumeLayout();
        foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls.OfType<LiveControl>())
            c.Update();
    }
};

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls.OfType<LiveControl>())                
        c.Invalidate();                    
}
```

But the problem is that as in the above code, each `LiveControl`'s `OnPaint` invalidates all of the `LiveControl`s, it causes infinite calls of `OnPaint` which causes problems for other controls on the form (they work very slow with delays).

To solve this I edited the code for `OnPaint` like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (!((DrawPanel)Parent).Invalidating)
    {
        ((DrawPanel)Parent).Invalidating = true;
        ((DrawPanel)Parent).InvalidatedCount = 0;
        foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls.OfType<LiveControl>())                
            c.Invalidate();            
    }
    else
    {
        ((DrawPanel)Parent).InvalidatedCount++;
        if (((DrawPanel)Parent).InvalidatedCount == ((DrawPanel)Parent).Controls.OfType<LiveControl>().Count())
        { 
            ((DrawPanel)Parent).InvalidatedCount = 0; ((DrawPanel)Parent).Invalidating = false;  
        }
    }
}
```

But the `OnPaint` method is still being called nonstop.
Does anybody has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: downvoter, would you please say why?

Comment: try to detach paint event on the OnPaint event and after completing the task register it again on the control.. that may help you to overcome from infinite loop

Comment: @NiranjanKala if I detach the OnPaint event, the `Invalidate()` won't do any good.

Comment: Since `Invalidate` is causing `Paint`, calling `Invalidate` from `OnPaint` is not a good idea. What really are you trying to achieve with that code?

Comment: Not my down-vote, but having an obvious endless loop shows a lack of research. - Calling Invalidate in Paint is an endless-loop. Period.

Comment: I couldn't see any flickering in the solution which I proposed for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39948820/3110834). Did you try that? B the way, surely invalidating in paint event is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invalidate` triggers `Paint` . Calling `Invalidate` in `Paint` is an endless-loop. Don't do that!

Flicker will go away if **all** controls that show it have `DoubleBuffering` on. **Note** that to turn on `DoublBuffering` you may need to **subclass** some of them, like `Panels`, `FlowLayoutPanels` or `DGVs`.. In fact only `Form` exposes it and only `PictureBox` has it on by default.

You also need to make sure all **unnecessary** `Invalidates` are eliminated. - Usually you need `Invalidate` only when **data** you need in **drawing** have **changed**. I don't see **any** drawing in your code at all. Otherwise you sometimes may need to call `Refresh` to eliminate **tearing**, i.e. 'tails' or 'traces'.

Answer (score 1):

I would not deal with OnPaint at all. I you want to make custom paint do it in the Paint event.

You should never call Invalidate() in a paint update situation.
If you have problems with flicker have you tried to set DoubleBuffered to true on your custom controls and container?

If you invalidate DrawPanel by calling DrawPanel.Invalidate() one override has a flag called `bool invalidateChildren`. Have you tried to set that to true?

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried `DoubleBuffered` it is making the result worse. leaving trails all over the other controls. `DrawPanel.Invalidate()`, with `invalidateChildren` set to true does the same thing as invalidates all children and also invalidates the parent too. I'll try dealing with it in Paint event to see what happens.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Then I think you are in serious trouble somewhere else. I have done what you are doing lots of times without any problems just letting Windows take care of paint, invalidate etc. Instead of derive from Panel, have you tried to derive from UserControl, and you could maybe put your PictureBox-derive into a UserControl as well?